# App crashes and do not open again, when saving something and going to next screen

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, inflate-exception

When I try to save something and go to the next screen, app crashes and never opens again. The app is supposed to go from main activity

I found this problem in my application.

```
    03-05 00:19:55.725 23397-23397/com.hitham.miscarros E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hitham.miscarros, PID: 23397
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hitham.miscarros/com.hitham.miscarros.Activities.ListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.hitham.miscarros.Activities.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.hitham.miscarros.Activities.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:61) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$ChildDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:961)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable$LayerState.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:1007)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:932)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:923)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:94)
        at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.mutate(LayerDrawable.java:912)
        at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.mutate(RippleDrawable.java:909)
        at android.view.View.applyBackgroundTint(View.java:17756)
        at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:17625)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.access$101(FloatingActionButton.java:83)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$ShadowDelegateImpl.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButton.java:1191)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButtonImplLollipop.setBackgroundDrawable(FloatingActionButtonImplLollipop.java:79)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:218)
        at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:170)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
        at com.hitham.miscarros.Activities.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:61) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3104) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:219) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1735) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

and here is the activity_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activities.ListActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_list" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is content_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Activities.ListActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_list"
android:background="#414141">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and here is the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hitham.miscarros"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

This problem showed up on api 22 device (android 5.1.1) and on api 23 emulator device while the app worked fine on api 26 and on api 25.

Comment: Could you add content_list.xml here please?

Comment: Did you add support library to your gradle file? there is a problem inflating android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton. you should have 
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0' in dependencies section of app/build.gradle

Comment: Would you please share your build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes Finally, Thank you very much both FaysalAhmed and  Elmira Frhn U really saved my day , I wish I could repay both of you, thanks.

Comment: @Hitham I have added an answer. Please check and mark as accepted if it works.

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the latest version 28.0.0 not 28.0.0-alpha1. Please change those and try again like this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1' 
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'  
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```